# SKAction playSoundFileNamed no audio through iphone speaker

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, sprite-kit, skaction

Has anyone had issues playing audio via the SKAction playSoundFileNamed using iOS Sprite Kit through the external speaker of your iOS device?  I have the following code that plays the M4A file with no issue through the headphones; however, no audio is played when I unplug the headphones stepping through code it executes just no sound.  I have another app that does not use this method and it plays with no issue.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKAction *sound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"blast.m4a" waitForCompletion:NO];
        [self runAction:sound];
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue but was able to fix it by setting AudioSession category to Playback. This causes the audio to be routed through the phone's speaker when headphones aren't plugged in.

```
// at the top of AppDelegate.m
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

// in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
NSError *error;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
```

You can find more information about this in Apple's [Audio Session Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Configuration/Configuration.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just to update I have installed IOS 7.0.4 today and retested and now I have audio on the external speakers so I'm going to assume it was a bug in IOS 7.0.3 as this is the only change I have made to the device.